# How do I use a PS4 controller with PPSSPP on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: controllers, linux, emulation, ppsspp

How can I configure and use a PS4 controller in PPSSPP on Ubuntu 16.04?

I tried to research it but most answers are for the Windows version.

Comment: Try DS4. Its an emulator that makes the PS4 controller appear as an XBox controller. Not sure if it will work on Ubuntu but you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use software like antimicro which is an opensource controller button mapping software for windows and linux to map your controller to the keyboard keys according to the controls of ppsspp.